# Memory leaks with 2D fully dynamic array

Tags: c, function, multidimensional-array, memory-leaks, dynamic-memory-allocation

I was given a task to implement a simple API for fully dynamic 2D array according to following interface.

```c
const int m = 2;
const int n = 3;
int **array = allocate_array (m, n);
assert (array != NULL);
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < m; i++)
{
  for (unsigned int j = 0; j < n; j++)
  {
    array[i][j] = i*10 + j;
  }
}
print_array (array, m, n);
free_and_nullify_array (&array, m);
printf("array points to %p\n", array);

/*
OUTPUT: 
 0  1  2
10 11 12
array points to (nil)
*/
```

I need to implement only 3 specific functions as part of the program.

While I have made an attempt to implement these functions, the program is currently indicating the presence of memory leaks. Despite my efforts, I was unable to identify the exact locations within the code where these memory leaks are occurring.

```c
//! allocate an m x n fully-dynamic 2D array
int** allocate_array (int m, int n)
{
    int ** arr = malloc (sizeof(int *) * m);
    if (!arr)
    {
        free(arr);
        arr = NULL;
        return NULL;
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = malloc (sizeof(int) * n);
        if (!arr[i])
        {
            free(arr[i]);
            arr[i] = NULL;
            return NULL;
        }
    }
    
    return arr;
}

//! free *array, a full-dynamic 2D array with m rows
//! and set its pointer to NULL
void free_and_nullify_array (int ***p_array, int m)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        free((*p_array)[i]);
        (*p_array)[i] = NULL;
    }
    
    free(*p_array);
    *p_array = NULL;
}

//! print an m x n fully-dynamic array
//! use one line per row, 2 digits per integer ("%2d"), one space
void print_array (int **array, int m, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            printf("%2d ", array[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters you have a typo in this for loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                ^^^^^
{
    arr[i] = malloc (sizeof(int) * n);
    if (!arr[i])
    {
        free(arr[i]);
        arr[i] = NULL;
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

You need to use the variable `m` instead of `n`.

Another problem in this for loop is if a memory was not allocated successfully then the memory allocated previously for the array of pointers and for one-dimensional arrays of integers is not freed.

You should write for example

```
//! allocate an m x n fully-dynamic 2D array
int ** allocate_array( int m, int n )
{
    int **arr = malloc( m * sizeof( int * ) );

    if ( arr != NULL )
    {
        int i = 0;

        while ( i < m && ( arr[i] = malloc( n * sizeof( int ) ) ) != NULL ) i++;

        if ( i != m )
        {
            for ( int j = 0; j < i; j++ ) free( arr[j] );
            free( arr );
            arr = NULL;
        }
    }
    
    return arr;
}
```

In general you should check that values of the parameters are positive values. And instead of using the signed integer type `int` for the parameters it will be much better to use the unsigned integer type `size_t`.

For example

```
//! allocate an m x n fully-dynamic 2D array
int ** allocate_array( size_t m, size_t n )
{
    int **arr = NULL;

    if ( m != 0 && n != 0 )
    {
        int **arr = malloc( m * sizeof( int * ) );

        if ( arr != NULL )
        {
            size_t i = 0;

            while ( i < m && ( arr[i] = malloc( n * sizeof( int ) ) ) != NULL ) i++;

            if ( i != m )
            {
                for ( size_t j = 0; j < i; j++ ) free( arr[j] );
                free( arr );
                arr = NULL;
            }
        }
    }

    return arr;
}
```

And within the function `free_and_nullify_array` this statement

```
(*p_array)[i] = NULL;
```

is redundant. You may remove it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Can you please explain a bit more why I should use `size_t` or guide me where I can read more about it?

Comment: @CStudent As size of an array can not be negative then there is no sense to use a signed integer type. And secondly memory allocation functions as for example malloc expect an argument of the type size_t.